# How do you check online status in electron.

Tags: electron

When using `navigator.onLine` it always returns true even when I disconnect my wifi.

Answer (score 0):

`navigator.onLine` check just if there is a connection, not if you are online or not.

One good way to check, it so send a request and check the response.

You can use something like isOnline :https://github.com/sindresorhus/is-online

Comment: I think the only real way to _always_ know is to poll that `navigator` property. I wonder, is there any way to set up events to emit when that property value changes?

Comment: you can use `online` and `offline` event ; https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorOnLine/onLine

Comment: This does not work at all;

I am also after the solution, but there is not much out there, even there documentation did'nt worked for me.
Maybe it works for you: [Docs](https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/online-offline-events)

I have opened Issue, if my problem got solved I will post answer here: [Issue](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/11290)

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it's always true is that there are some virtual machine adapters on your computer

https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/11290#issuecomment-348175127

Using https://github.com/sindresorhus/is-online as @sheplu suggested is a good solution.

But keep in my that if you call to isOnline many times (for example an interval of 2 seconds), it will crash your Electron app.